# Getting graphics object to draw with buffer strategy

Tags: java, swing, canvas, graphics, buffer

I've made a JFrame with a canvas on it and I want to draw on that canvas. At a later date the canvas will be updating many times a second so I am using a buffer strategy for this. Here is the code:

```
package mainPackage;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TickPainter {
    //just some presets for a window.
    public static JFrame makeWindow(String title, int width, int height) {
        JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame();
        mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainWindow.setSize(width, height);
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
        mainWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainWindow.setTitle(title);

        return mainWindow;      
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame mainWindow = makeWindow("Practice", 800, 600);
        Canvas mainCanvas = new Canvas();
        mainWindow.add(mainCanvas);
        mainCanvas.setSize(mainWindow.getWidth(), mainWindow.getHeight());
        mainCanvas.setBackground(Color.white);
        mainCanvas.createBufferStrategy(3);
        BufferStrategy bufferStrat = mainCanvas.getBufferStrategy();

        Graphics g = bufferStrat.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(250, 250, 250, 250);
        g.dispose();
        bufferStrat.show();
    }
}
```

The program does not draw the black rectangle as intended, I feel like I've missed something really obvious here and I just can't see it. At the moment the program just makes a blank white canvas. I feel like part of the issue is that the buffer is just passing the frame with the rectangle faster than I can see, but there is no frame to load after that so I don't know why it's doing this.

Comment: First, go read both the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) and [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html), they provide invaluable examples into how you're suppose to use a `BufferStrategy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `BufferStrategy` has a number of initial requirements which must be meet before it can be rendered to. Also, because of the nature of how it works, you might need to repeat a paint phases a number of times before it's actually accepted by the hardware layer.

I recommend going through the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) and [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html), they provide invaluable examples into how you're suppose to use a `BufferStrategy`

The following example uses a `Canvas` as the base component and sets up a rendering loop within a custom `Thread`.  It's very basic, but shows the basic concepts you'd need to implement...

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TestCanvas canvas = new TestCanvas();

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(canvas);
                frame.setTitle("Test");
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                canvas.start();
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestCanvas extends Canvas {

        private Thread thread;
        private AtomicBoolean keepRendering = new AtomicBoolean(true);

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        public void stop() {
            if (thread != null) {
                keepRendering.set(false);
                try {
                    thread.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public void start() {
            if (thread != null) {
                stop();
            }

            keepRendering.set(true);
            thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    createBufferStrategy(3);

                    do {
                        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
                        while (bs == null) {
                            System.out.println("get buffer");
                            bs = getBufferStrategy();
                        }
                        do {
                            // The following loop ensures that the contents of the drawing buffer
                            // are consistent in case the underlying surface was recreated
                            do {
                                // Get a new graphics context every time through the loop
                                // to make sure the strategy is validated
                                System.out.println("draw");
                                Graphics graphics = bs.getDrawGraphics();

                                // Render to graphics
                                // ...
                                graphics.setColor(Color.RED);
                                graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
                                // Dispose the graphics
                                graphics.dispose();

                                // Repeat the rendering if the drawing buffer contents
                                // were restored
                            } while (bs.contentsRestored());

                            System.out.println("show");
                            // Display the buffer
                            bs.show();

                            // Repeat the rendering if the drawing buffer was lost
                        } while (bs.contentsLost());
                        System.out.println("done");
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } while (keepRendering.get());
                }
            });
            thread.start();
        }

    }

}
```

Remember, the point of `BufferStrategy` is to give you full control over the painting process, so it works outside the normal painting process generally implemented by AWT and Swing

*"At a later date the canvas will be updating many times a second so I am using a buffer strategy for this"* - Before going down the "direct to hardware" solution, I'd consider using a Swing `Timer` and the normal painting process to see how well it works